# Implementing medium editor in a django app

Tags: python, django, frontend, wysiwyg

How can I use https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor in my django app, I try creating a form with:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/medium-editor@latest/dist/js/medium-editor.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/medium-editor@latest/dist/css/medium-editor.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
<script>var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');</script>

<div class="editable" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

But nothing shows up

I tried to enter it manually into my project but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the last two lines, so that the HTML element is established in the DOM before the code runs.

```
<div class="editable" contenteditable="true"></div>

<script>var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');</script>
```

Another option is to add a listener to the call to make sure the DOM content is in place before the code is run

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');
});
</script>
```